# Running different test suites using testng and maven

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using TestNg and Maven with the surefire plugin to run my tests.  I have several different components that I want to be able to run at different times using the same pom.  Currently to do this I have several different XML files defining a test suite and I have the pom set up so i can do mvn test -Dtestfile=/path and use that suite instead.

I was wondering if there is a way to combine the XML files into one file and chose base off testnames or some other system?

EDIT:  I have all my tests defined with Smoke, Sanity, Regression already and I would like to be able to run all Regressions for a given component.  If I run through the TestNG CLI, I am able to give -testnames comp1,comp2,comp3,etc. where each component is defined in one xml suite which contains multiple tests ().  I was wondering if there was any way to do this in maven short of using the exec:java plugin.

Answer (score 8):

TestNG supports groups of tests, either by specifying groups on test classes/methods in the test cases themselves, or in the suite.xml file. By using groups, you can put all your tests in one xml file. See [Groups](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) in the TestNG user guide.

The surefire plugin allows tests to be included or excluded based on group:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <groups>${testng.groups}</groups>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

You can put all your tests in one xml file, and then choose which ones to run by setting the group or groups to include in the ${testng.groups} property, which should be a comma-delimited list of group names.

You can define value for the ${testng.groups} property in the POM using profiles, or on the command-line `-Dtestng.groups=[groups to run]`.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is to define different profiles

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>t1</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
```

and call from command line via mvn -Pt1 ...
or define a property in the profile and use that property in the configuraiton.

Comment: I tried doing this. So, did you set different testng.xml files for different profiles?

Answer (score 2):

Also note that TestNG allows you to combine multiple suites into one, e.g. if you wanted to combine your api and ui smoke tests into one suite:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="uber-smoke-suite" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="smoke_api.xml" />
    <suite-file path="smoke_ui.xml" />
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

That way you can also create an uber suite too that combines all your tests into one, but still allows you to run single suite if necessary, e.g.:

```
-Dtestfile=smoke
-Dtestfile=smoke_api
-Dtestfile=smoke_ui
```