# Skip Test cases based on URL

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have different projects for web ordering. I have POM framework with `TestNG` and `maven`. I have multiple test cases that I have automated in different projects depending upon flows.

Flows can be:

Takeout for one client
Steps:

1. Add Item
2. Checkout

Takeout for another client
Steps:

1. Select Location
2. Add Item
3. Checkout

As we can see there is an additional step to select location for second client. So, what I want to do is have one project and that contains test cases for both the client separately in different folders and package and run it using `testng.xml` ? If I add all the test case in `testng.xml` and run it, then i will have many failed test cases which I don't want. So is there any way how to run only specific test cases depending on url or depending upon clients name? There is a way to do with `IAnnotationTransformer` but I can't think of the logic. Help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using TestNG Groups? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721431/864369

Comment: I did but that doesn't solve my problem as I have to update the `pom` file every time if I want to run different groups .

Comment: You could use an environment variable in the pom so that is static. Then, when building via command line, you use the `-D` option to set what the variable is.

Comment: Okay and thank you for your comments, but what happens when I run it using Jenkins for CI ?

Comment: When running via Jenkins, you can again specify the `-D` argument to select which groups you want to run.

Comment: Ok let me try with environment variable in pom.